# ¿Cómo habilitar una página una vez se ejecute todo el código javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy realizando una página de registro y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de determinar cuando se han completado todas las llamadas que realizo desde el js y que están contenidas dentro del

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        CargarCombo();
        CargarOpciones();
    });
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es que una vez se completen esas llamadas, pueda manipular la página e introducir los datos que quiera. Y, hasta que no se completen esas llamadas, que no deje pulsar en ninguna parte.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo resolví de una forma muy sencilla. Esto lo he puesto al principio de cada JS y con esot logro que una vez se acabe ajax, se quite el loader y así hace la simulación de que está cargando.

```
    function loading_gif() {
    $('body').append('<div class="loader"></div>');
}

function remove_loading_gif() {
    $('.loader').remove();
}

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    loading_gif();
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    remove_loading_gif();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No web no debería tener ese tipo de comportamiento. Es decir debería permitir interacción al usuario mientras se carga la información.

En cualquier caso te recomiendo gestionarlas con Promise.all, async y await para saber cuando han terminado las llamadas AJAX.

https://gist.github.com/indiesquidge/5960274889e17102b5130e8bd2ce9002

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocupar la funcion when, la cual se ejecuta cuando tus peticiones hallan terminado, te dejo un link para que puedas aprender mas de ello. [.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when( CargarCombo(), CargarOpciones()  ).then(function(dataCombo,dataOpciones){ })
```